# Customizer JS API: Defining active_callback for a section

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, api

WordPress allows to use `active_callback` argument to display a section for a specific page(s) in the Customizer. In PHP it looks like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'section_id', array(
  'title' => 'Contact Page Options',
  'priority' => 1,
  'panel' => 'panel_id',
  'active_callback' => 'is_contact_page',
) );
```

Then we can create `is_contact_page` function that will do all the checks.

I am wondering what is a correct way to use `active_callback` when creating a section using Customizer JS API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, however you will need to use a different approach, and you may need to do a but more work because `active_callback` here in PHP can directly connect with the database to find out whether the current query is for the contact page. The Customizer controls by default just has access to the `previewUrl`. So if you can rely on the URL to determine whether something is the contact page, all you need to do is this:

```
function isContactPage() {
    return /contact/.test( wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl.get() );
}

var section = new wp.customize.Section( 'section_id', {
    title: 'Contact Page Options',
    customizeAction: 'Customizing',
    priority: 1,
    panel: 'panel_id',
    active: isContactPage() // Initial state.
} );
wp.customize.section.add( section );

// Update the active state whenever the previewed URL changes.
wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl.bind( function activeCallback() {
    section.active.set( isContactPage() ); // Update state.
} );
```

A more robust way to set the `active` state would require doing the PHP logic in `is_contact_page` and then sending this in a message from the preview window to the controls window (which is what is being done with the `active_callback` behind the scenes). This is what is done in the [Customize Posts](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts) plugin. However there is [#36582](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36582) which proposes exporting the main query to JS and send in a message from the preview window to the controls window as an additional value in `wp.customize.state`.